# Ruby: 'bundle exec' throws error for all shell commands

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems

In my project, I have a Gem that contains a shell script in its bin folder, let's call the script do_something.sh.

do_something.sh actually executes a ruby script using Jruby command, the script is called ruby_script.rb.

I am trying to call do_something.sh from my project using:

`bundle exec do_something.sh`

it keeps throwing errors for all shell commands in the script. I erased all the contents of the script and added only one line "echo 'Hello'" and it is still throwing the following error

`NoMethodError: undefined method echo' for main:Object
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@projectName/gems/gemName/bin/do_something.sh:10:in'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@projectName/bin/do_something.sh:23:in load'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@projectName/bin/do_something.sh:23:in'`

**Edit#1**
All the files has execute permission.

I also tried to put ruby_script.rb in the bin directory where are files are executables (according to a rule in the gemspec file) and tried calling

`bundle exec ruby_script.rb`

I get the error "bundler: command not found: ruby_script.rb"

`bundle exec ruby ruby_script.rb`

I get the error "ruby: No such file or directory -- ruby_script.rb (LoadError)"

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve it? I want to be able to either run do_something.sh or ruby_script.rb. Right now, ruby_script.rb is not recognised and do_something.sh does not recognise the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally after two days, I was able to make it work.

`bundle install` installs my GEM and creates a ruby wrapper by default to sh files in the 'bin' directory. So, when I call my script using `bundle exec` the ruby wrapper gets called first and it calls my script using a ruby 'load' function. This load function expects a ruby file and that is why all my shell script in the file threw errors, because they were expected to be in ruby.

A workaround to this is installing my gem before 'bundle install' using the following command:

`gem install --no-wrapper my-gem`

Apparently this command disabled creating the ruby wrapper and I was finally able to call the script using `bundle execute do_something.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying sh when you run bundle exec. The `NoMethodError` is from the script being executed in ruby and not sh.

`bundle exec sh do_something.sh`

Comment: Still throws an error, the file "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@projectName/bin/do_something.sh" actually contains ruby script that calls my actual script in: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@projectName/gems/gemName/bin/do_something.sh

Comment: It calls it using this line : load Gem.bin_path('gemName', 'do_something.sh', version)

Comment: Well you should specify ruby then. `bundle exec ruby bin/do_something` To execute the shell script from within ruby you can use [exec](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) or [backticks](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60) or [system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system). You may need to read the file instead of load it.

Comment: I tried this but it cannot detect the file using 'bundle exec ruby bin/do_something' throws the following error 'ruby: No such file or directory -- /path/to/script/do_something.rb (LoadError)'

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work. [Setting_up_permissions_on_a_script](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Setting_up_permissions_on_a_script)

**First:** you have to change the `mode` for the file using `chomd +x file_path`

**Second:** Now you can call either by `bundle exec file_path` or `./file_path`

**N.B**

1: Don't forget to add `#!/bin/sh` on top of the file.

2: And do check with [deploy-a-shell-script-with-ruby-gem-and-install-in-bin-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27988355/3098330) will definitely help you.

Hope this help you!

Comment: Why is this a chmod problem? the file already has execution privileges? Also, it is able to read the command, it just does not able to understand it.

Comment: Also ./file_path does not work because the file is not in the project, it is in a GEM that is loaded somewhere else.

Comment: you have to make file as `executable` in order to make it work.

Comment: @Sarah Will you please tell me whether my answer has been worked for you or not ?

Comment: The scripts are already executable, they have the following permissions '-rwxr-xr-x'

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rubygems Specification Reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#executables), executables included in the gem

> ... must be executable Ruby files. Files that use bash or other interpreters will not work.

In order to to add an executable to a gem please make sure to read the [Adding an executable](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable) section on Rubygems Guide.

Eventually you'll be able to run the executable like this:

```
bundle exec do_something
```

where `bundle exec` part is optional.

Comment: It is executable, the script has the following permissions '-rwxr-xr-x'

Comment: Thanks @dskecse it turned out it wasn't a 'bundle exec' problem, it was how the GEM was initially installed, please take a look at my answer