# Is it possible to use gems to deploy non-ruby executables?

Tags: rubygems

Basically is it possible to use gems as a generic package manager of executables and disregard ruby altogether?

Let's say I have created a batch script and a bash script which do some arcane stuff, which is impossible to do with Ruby.

Is it possible to package them in a gem and allow users to install them with `gem install`?

The main problem is that while gemspec allows me to provide a list of executables, it assumes they're ruby scripts. Because of this `gem install` creates some platform-specific wrappers which boil down to

```
$ ruby file-which-is-listed-as-executable-in-gemspec
```

This obviously doesn't work for my batch and and bash scripts.

The reason I can't just create a ruby executable which, in turn, executes those scripts is that I'll lose the current environment. The batch file sets environment variables which need to remain after the execution and the bash script is supposed to be invoked with `source` so the variables it exports remain. Invoking any of these with ruby will undo all environment var changes as they will only happen in the ruby's process environment.

The reason I'm considering gems at all is that those scripts eventually do call ruby executables and this is essentially a ruby gem. I want to provide the environment setup helpers along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found that the answer is "almost". It can work if one installs the gem with `--no-wrapper` then all executables will be added with no wrappers to the bin dir. It's kind of unpleasant, but it works.

Relevant issue: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/88

Another question (basically the same as this): [Deploy a shell script with Ruby gem and install in bin directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701726/deploy-a-shell-script-with-ruby-gem-and-install-in-bin-directory)